# What is the 4-momentum of a moving photon with a certain energy in natural units?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum

If a photon is travelling along the x-axis with an energy $E$ then the 4-momentum of the photon in natural units is:
$$\begin{pmatrix}E \\E\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
I don't understand why the first component of the 3-momentum is equal to $E$, i.e. why $p_x = E$ ?

Comment: Do you mean why do we specifically take $p_x = E$ rather that $\sqrt{p_x^2 + p_y^2 + p_z^2} = E$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Lorentz “length” of the four-momentum vector $(E, \mathbf{p})$ is the mass:

$$E^2-\mathbf{p}^2=m^2.$$

Photons are massless so $m=0$ and $E=|\mathbf{p}|$.